# How to close all sessions properly using tmux?

Tags: tmux

I am using tmux version 2.7.  What is a proper way to close all sessions so that there is no session at all running with tmux?

Any process running inside the session (such as a Rails server or Django server) should be terminated properly, without any of them dangling.

Answer (score 1):

Ether of `tmux kill-server` or `pkill tmux` will do it (they have the same effect). All processes inside tmux will be sent SIGHUP by the kernel, what each does with it is up to the individual application.

Comment: if I want the CTRL-C `SIGINT` and actually see each shell is just waiting for command, how would I do that?

Comment: You would need to write a script to do that yourself, you can use tmux send-keys and capture-pane and so on. But any program where it matters should behave the same on SIGHUP as SIGINT.

Comment: ok... now I know one way: `tmux ls` to see the sessions. Now `tmux a -t <session>` to attach to the session. Press CTRL-c to stop anything you are running (if any), and press Ctrl-d to come out